# discord.js cannot read property 'roles' of null

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm having some trouble with my discord bot and I could really use some help

Currently my bot executes this piece of code, and it works perfectly most of the time:

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.has('917521104908742736')) //muted role
{
        return message.delete();
}
```

However, from time to time, the bot crashes randomly, giving out the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
```

I don't know what to do anymore, and even worse is that the program crashes randomly, so I don't know what exactly causes the error. Could you help me, please?

Comment: If the bot receives DMs, this may happen

Comment: YES, thank you very much, that was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The message object doesn't seem to have the member property (maybe because the message has been sent in DMs), try to add the interogation mark for [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) :

```js
if(message.member?.roles.cache.has('917521104908742736')) {
  return message.delete();
}
```

Comment: I get an Unexpected Token error on the dot after the question mark

Comment: Are you using Node.js 14? Try to check with `node -v`

Answer (score 0):

The bot simply receives DMs. Check if it's a DM, and return early if it is:

```js
if (!message.guild) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === 'RoleId')) {
 return message.delete();
}
```